# Javascript return a NEW object with the key successfully translated

Tags: javascript, object

trying to solve this problem:
This function will take an object representing a student's data, a key that needs changing, and its English translation.

and so far I managed to solve it with this code:

```
function translateKey(student, keyToChange, translation) {
  student[translation] = student[keyToChange];
  delete student[keyToChange];
  return student;
}

const student = {
  firstName: "Napoleon",
  surname: "Bonaparte",
  ilsSontMorts: true,
};

console.log(translateKey(student, "ilsSontMorts", "isDead"));
```

but the second request is to return these changes into a NEW OBJECT,  with the key successfully translated E.g:

```
{
       firstName: "Napoleon",
       surname: "Bonaparte",
       isDead: true,'
    }
```

I tried different "solutions" like

```
return new Object(student)
```

but it doesn't work.. how can I return my results as new object?

thank you for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer below solution

```js
function translateKey(student, keyToChange, translation) {
const newObj = {...student}
  newObj[translation] = newObj[keyToChange];
  delete newObj[keyToChange];
  return newObj;
}

const student = {
  firstName: "Napoleon",
  surname: "Bonaparte",
  ilsSontMorts: true,
};


console.log('new Object',translateKey(student, "ilsSontMorts", "isDead"));
console.log('oldObject',student)
```

Comment: this works beautifully! So the only thing I needed to do was to create a new Object with {...student}  and then work on the new object created! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Your function `translateKey()` modifies incoming object. To prevent that, you should create duplicated object, either by `{...student}` or by `Object.assign()`

```
function translateKey(student, keyToChange, translation) {
  const newStudent = Object.assign({}, student);
  newStudent[translation] = student[keyToChange];
  delete newStudent[keyToChange];
  return newStudent;
}

const student = {
  firstName: "Napoleon",
  surname: "Bonaparte",
  ilsSontMorts: true,
};

console.log(translateKey(student, "ilsSontMorts", "isDead"));
console.log(student);
```

Or a bit dirty way, keep your function as it is and create new object when calling your function (would not recommend)

```
console.log(translateKey({...student}, "ilsSontMorts", "isDead"));
```

Comment: thank you! I solved using {...student} which I think is the same as Object.assign().